# Multiple IF() functions not nested

Tags: excel, excel-formula

This functions perfectly... (Cell displays message in quotes when true.)

```
  =IF(AE4,"Upload Spectra into Uniflow no matter insurance.","")
```

This does not function at all... (Cell is blank. Does not display either messages in quotes when TRUE.)

```
=IF(AE4,"Upload Spectra into Uniflow no matter insurance.","")&IF(T4,"Add height and weight ","")
```

[image]
[image]

I think this is an error with excel. The true false check boxes that these are linked to are functioning perfectly. If you have any questions please ask, and thank you in advanced.

This is NOT what I am looking for...

=IF(AE4,"Upload Spectra into Uniflow no matter insurance.",IF(T4,"Add height and weight ",""))

This is what I am looking for...

If both AE4 and T4 are true then the cell should display, "Upload Spectra into Uniflow no matter insurance. Add height and weight."

If just AE4 is true then the cell should display, "Upload Spectra into Uniflow no matter insurance. "

If just T4 is true then the cell should display, "Add height and weight. "

[image]

The equivalent java code for the desired output is as follows. All text should be displayed in one cell.

```
public static void main (String[] args){   

boolean AE4;
boolean T4;

if (AE4){
System.out.println("Upload Spectra into Uniflow no matter insurance.");}

if (T4);{
System.out.println("Add height and weight");}

}
```

Comment: `does not function` is not very descriptive.  What goes wrong, specifically?

Comment: What does 'does not function' mean? What result do you get?

Comment: `=IF(AE4,`..... what?  What are you trying to compare `AE4` to?  Is `AE4` just a `TRUE`/`FALSE`, a checkbox?  Please provide more detail.

Comment: This formula does for me what I assume it is supposed to do based on the formula. if cell `AE4` is `TRUE` it shows "Upload Spectra into Uniflow no matter insurance.", and if cell `T4` is `TRUE` it shows "Add height and weight " and if both are true it shows "Upload Spectra into Uniflow no matter insurance.Add height and weight " As I would expect it to.

Comment: What ever the problem is, it is not the formula. It is either your expectations of what the formula should do or the cells are not what you think they are.  Either way we cannot help without more information.  To reiterate; there is nothing wrong with the formulas that we can see.

Comment: Is T4 a logical (boolean)? Use =islogical() to check.

Comment: I agree with the others, this should work.  Although... if this is a syntax issue... in your first equation you are looking at `AE5` and you say it works perfectly... but in your second equation you are looking at `AE4`.  It could be *that's* your problem.  If not, see everybody else's suggestions above. :)

Comment: You need to come to the conclusion that your AE4 and T4 are not functioning as you expect them.  The error is there, those cells may contain the check box but may not hold the Boolean output.  The formula will not see the checkbox, thus the link to a cell where the Boolean is placed.

Comment: There is likely an error with excel. When using an IF() statement to check AE4 or T4 the desired TRUE or FALSE result is displayed. When I add the IF()&IF() nothing is displayed no matter what combination the TRUE and FALSES are in.

Comment: Can you, for fun, stick those `IF()` statements inside of a `=CONCATENATE()` formula instead of using the shorthand `&`. Furthermore (since your `AE5` has been switched to a `AE4` in recent edits, please confirm that your `if()` formulas are referencing the same cells when testing separately (`ae4` and `t4`) as they are in the `=CONCATENATE()` version. I believe you that you have tested this up the wazoo and it sounds very frustrating.

Comment: Also, do you have any Macros/VBA happening on this workbook? If so, does any of it shut of automatic calculations on certain events like `worksheet_selectionchange()` or `application.screenupdating()` or what-have-you?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This will do what you want - you're missing an ampersand.

```
=TRIM(IF(AE4,"Upload Spectra into Uniflow no matter insurance. ","")&IF(T4,"Add height and weight.",""))
```

Comment: WOW IT WORKED!!! I have no idea what TRIM does but it worked. You 100% resolved my problem. Now I can just keep adding IF statements with comments.

Comment: I added a space at the end of `Upload Spectra into Uniflow no matter insurance. `, to concatenate the IFs in case both conditions are true. If only the first is true I want to remove this space - that's what the TRIM is doing. As I said, to concatenate both IFs you were missing the `&` between them.

Comment: But the odd thing I noticed, as I look back at the revisions of the post, the missing ampersand (&) was in the formula in the [original post](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/47819599/1)

Comment: It happens all too often unfortunately.

Answer (score 3):

> If both AE4 and T4 are true then the cell should display, "Upload Spectra into Uniflow no matter insurance. Add height and weight."
>
> If just AE4 is true then the cell should display, "Upload Spectra into Uniflow no matter insurance. "
>
> If just T4 is true then the cell should display, "Add height and weight. "

If the cells are blank, the `If(AE4` will trigger a #Value! error, so you may want to check for blank cells, too. As far as I see it, you are missing commas in your formula. The following works fine in my tests:

```
=IF(AND(NOT(ISBLANK(AE4)),NOT(ISBLANK(T4)),AE4,T4),"Upload Spectra into Uniflow no matter insurance. Add height and weight.",
    IF(AND(NOT(ISBLANK(AE4)),AE4),"Upload Spectra into Uniflow no matter insurance.",
         IF(AND(NOT(ISBLANK(T4)),T4),"Add height and weight.","no data")))
```

[image]

Edit after comment: If you need to include many more conditions, you better use a matrix for the combinations and lookup formulas instead of nested IFs. Nested IFs become very unwieldy after three levels of nesting and a lookup table approach will be a lot easier to maintain.

Comment: Heyya, nice job I gave you a thumbs up, but I am planning on adding multiple other IF statements with comments. In other words, the formula would get very complicated if I had to add a add an IF statments that has every combination of every IF statement.  The information about blanks was very helpful though. In Java the code for the output I am trying to get is as follows.

Comment: I added a suggestion for another approach.

Comment: Looking at your sheet gives me the creeps, really. No offense meant, but these hundreds of check boxes are sooo ***NOT*** necessary and so hard to maintain. What do you do when you have to enter a new row of data? You are also pre-filling rows and bulking up the workbook unnecessarily. This is very inefficient. You may want to look into Excel tables and using text instead of check boxes. Y or N will be as good as a tick or no tick and so much easier to set up. Excel Table objects will inherit data validation and formulas in each row, so no need to pre-fill. Just saying.

Answer (score 1):

This does exactly what you ask it to do, the only difference is that my version of Excel uses the semicolon (;) as argument delimiter and yours uses a comma (,)

[image: Formula]
[image: Situation 1]
[image: Situation 2]
[image: Situation 3]
[image: Situation 4]

Comment: I am sorry for confusing you all this. This maybe a problem with Excel. After attempting to use the formula that is not working it causes no formulas to work in the cell afterwards. So some odd things are going on here. I tried to post a screenshot, but I do not know if that worked since I am a new member.

Comment: @MatthewHamilton, in any case post the link to the screenshot if it clarifies your issue.

Comment: I believe one screenshot is displayed now. I am adding more. There are some restrictions for new members on adding screen shots.

Comment: It sounds like you are saying that the cell shows the formula as text and that any formula pasted into that cell does the same. If that's the case format the cell as General. I'm guessing it's set to text right now. I'm not sure why Excel does this but it happens to me occasionally. To test this, write a simple formula, format it as text, refresh the cell. It should show the formula as text. On mine I have to put the cursor in the edit bar and press enter to have it recalc as described. Good luck!